# Error in a line on big CSV imported to BigQuery

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, grep

I'm trying to import a big CSV file to BigQuery (2.2 GB+). This is the error I get:

```
"Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 33, but line starting at position:254025076 contains only 26 columns."
```

There are more errors on that file – and on that file only, out of one per state. Usually I would skip the faulty lines, but then I would lose a lot of data.

What can be a good way to check and correct the errors in a file that big?

**EDIT:** This is what seems to happen in the file. It's one single line and it breaks between "Instituto" and "Butantan". As a result, BigQuery parses it as one line with 26 columns and another with nine columns. That repeats a lot.

[image]

As far as I've seen, it's just with Butantan, but sometimes the first word is described differently (I caught "Instituto" and "Fundação"). Can I correct that maybe with grep on the command line? If so, what syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually 2.2GB is quite manageble size. It can be quickly pre-processed with command line tools or simple python script on any +/- modern laptop/desktop or on a small VM in GCP.

You can start from looking at the problematic row:

```
head -n 254025076 your_file.csv | tail -n 1
```

If problematic rows just have missing values for last columns - you can use "--allow_jagged_rows" [loading CSV option](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options).

Otherwise I'm usually using simple python script like this:

```
import fileinput

def process_line(line):
    # your logic to fix line
    return line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for line in fileinput.input():
        print(process_line(line))
```

and run it with:

```
cat your_file.csv | python3 preprocess.py > new_file.csv
```

**UPDATE**:
For newline characters in value - try BigQuery "Allow quoted newlines" [option](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options).

Comment: The problemmatic rows are interpreted as broken by BigQuery but as whole by DB-Browser, so I'm exporting from DB-Browser first to see what happens.